# CodeIgniter not setting csrf cookie with Nginx

Tags: codeigniter, cookies, nginx, csrf-protection

I'm using nginx and I can't login to the admin panel. It's using https so that may be a part of it.

Here are the relevant portions of my `nginx.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /ssl.key;

    server_name mysite.com;
    root /var/www/mysite;
    index index.php;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    client_max_body_size 200M;
```

...

```
location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:6000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        fastcgi_param PYRO_ENV production;
        include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your form code, CSRF config, and any login code as well. I don't see how Ngix can be preventing CSRF checks as it is the same as any other cookie or form input. The problem is likely with the code or config of CI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to use `www.mysite.com` for `server_name` instead of just `mysite.com`.